# FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation returns null

Tags: android

I have singleton for location service

```
public class LocationService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    public static final String TAG = LocationService.class.getSimpleName();

    private static LocationService instance;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public Location location;
    private Context context;

    private LocationService (Context context) {

        this.context = context;

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(60 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

    }

    public static LocationService getInstance(Context context){

        if (null == instance){
            instance = new LocationService(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        this.location = location;

        if (location != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        this.location = location;

        Log.i(TAG, "Location changed.");
        Log.i(TAG, location.toString());

    }
}
```

I start it in `MainActivity` by calling in `onCreate`

```
LocationService locationService = LocationService.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

But my location is always null and `onLocationChanged` doesnt get called

`OnConnected` is being called, I checked in debugger, but `location` inside is null

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: May be you can check location service whether it was enable. Normally, Play Store Service will never trigger "onLocationChanged" if location service is disabled and also if it long enough the last location should be null.

Answer (score 1):

If your last location is null you need to register to get updates at least one time as to get a first last location.

[Check the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) for "Request Location Updates".

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if location is enabled from the settings:

```
private void checkLocationEnabled() {
    // check if location is enabled
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
            && !manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        showSettingsAlert(mContext);
    }
}


public void showSettingsAlert(final Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Location Settings");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Location is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu ?");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```